# Does vector<atomic_bool> involves coalescing vector elements?

Tags: c++, coalescing

As stated in the subject: does `vector<atomic_bool>` involves coalescing vector elements in the same way of `vector<bool>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has only one specialization, `std::vector<bool>`. `bool` and `std::atmoic_bool` are two different types and as a result `std::vector<atomic_bool>` will work like other `std::vector<T>` of type `T`.

Comment: Actually, the underlying question was this: how could I implement a thread-safe bitvector? To get an idea, I would like a kind of ```vector<bool>```such that multiple threads can access the _i_-th element (bit) without data races.

Comment: @grd -- ask that as a question! The answer is to write a loop with `std::compare_exchange_strong`.